# Why do these two javascript 2d-arrays behave differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my function, I have defined two arrays, the first (*array1*), has a pre-initialized length. I added the second array (*array2*) just for testing because I thought the first was behaving strangely.

My code:

```js
function test(n = 3) {
  array1 = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n));
  array2 = [
    [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined]
  ];

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array1) + " (array 1) <br/>" + JSON.stringify(array2) + " (array 2)<br/><br/><hr/>";


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array1[i][0] = i;
    array2[i][0] = i;
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(array1) + " (array 1) <br/>" + JSON.stringify(array2) + " (array 2)<br/><br/><hr/>";

}
```

```html
<button onclick="test();">Press to test</button>

<br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In the `for` loop, I try to change the first value of the second dimensions. It should output `[[0, undefined, undefined], [1, undefined, undefined], [2, undefined, undefined]]`, like the second array does.

My questions are: why does this happen? And, how can I make a pre-initialized array with length *n* in both dimensions, that behaves like the second array?

Comment: Sharing an article, why not to use new Array(), hope this helps -> https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

> The **`fill()`** method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.

takes a **static value** and fills the array with it. Therefore you get in every element of `array1` the same array of the filling.

```js
function test(n = 3) {
    var array1 = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n)),
        array2 = [[undefined, undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined, undefined]],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array1[i][0] = i;
        array2[i][0] = i;
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = array1 + " (array 1) <br/>" + array2 + " (array 2)<br/><br/><i>The commas with nothing in between mean undefined.</i>";
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(array2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test();">Press to test</button><br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

To get an independent filled array, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and map a new array with mapped values.

```js
var array = Array.from({ length: 3 }, _ => Array.from({ length: 3 }, _ => 4));

array[0][0] = 0;
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 9):

That's because in case of `array1` it contains three arrays, but all three of them point to the same reference variable, that was evaluated when `new Array(n)` was executed:

```
var array1 = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n));
```

So when the `for` loop runs over `array1` it is setting the value of the same array reference, while in case of `array2` those three arrays are different reference variables.

Here's a slightly modified version of your snippet. Notice the entries into console when the value of `array1`'s element is being changed. In case of `array1` all three child arrays are changing, while in case of `array2` the array referenced under the loop using index `i` is the only one that changes.

```js
function test(n = 3) {
  array1 = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n));
  array2 = [
    [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    [undefined, undefined, undefined]
  ];

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array1) + " (array 1) <br/>" + JSON.stringify(array2) + " (array 2)<br/><br/><i>The commas with nothing in between mean undefined.</i><hr/>";


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array1[i][0] = i;
    array2[i][0] = i;
    console.log("Array 1: " + JSON.stringify(array1));
    console.log("Array 2: " + JSON.stringify(array2));
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(array1) + " (array 1) <br/>" + JSON.stringify(array2) + " (array 2)<br/><br/><i>The commas with nothing in between mean undefined.</i><hr/>";

}
```

```html
<button onclick="test();">Press to test</button>

<br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! However, how can I define `array1` so it is pre-initialized? The second array works for this case of n = 3, but, what if, for example, n = 5?

Comment: I'd probably do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/966239/5894241), but Nina Scholz has explained a different method in her answer as well.

Comment: Creating an entire for-loop seems a bit too much code for such a simple task :) so I think I'll use Nina's answer.